# Moving magento page titles to a new place

Tags: magento, page-title

I'm working on a magento website and would like to move all titles to another place(See images for an example).

**Right now it looks like this**

https://puu.sh/x2bGu/4d47221c65.jpg

**It must look like this**

https://puu.sh/x2buz/36bf62ecf5.jpg

It's need to be done for the following templates. (1column and 2columns-left templates)

How can i place the magento titles to a new block??

Answer (score 0):

Simply write below code where you want to display page title.

```
?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle(); ?>
```

Comment: Not working. On a sub category page or procuct page, it will show the full path, just like breadcrumbs.

[Home] -> [Category] -> [Current page].